# Login with Different Authentication Providers

Tags: support, login, google, facebook

What will happen if I login via Google and via Facebook to Stack Overflow and Google as well as Facebook use the same email address? Will Stack Overflow create **two separate accounts** or will it "merge" accounts and use **only one**?

**EDIT**

I was using login via Google all the time. When I tried Facebook I got an error saying I am not able to login so that's why asked the question.

However, when tried a few minutes later with Facebook I was able to login successfully. Also I was using **the same account as with login via Gmail**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried it? I think it will add another account. But you can add your logins yourself. Go to [your profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/205246/tom) click on `my login`.

> [image]

Now click on `add more logins...` and add both Facebook's OpenId there.

[image]